# Using curly braces quantifier \d{5} in search pattern in Vim

Tags: regex, vim

I can't seem to use this pattern in Vim: `\d{4}` (but can only use `\d\d\d\d`) while searching; Any idea whats going on?

**note:**

- I am new to Vim
- I used `/` in `Normal Mode` and typed the pattern.

Comment: `\d\{4}` should work.

Answer (score 15):

```
/\d\{4}
```

or

```
/\v\d{4}
```

read `:h magic` for details

Comment: Cool, thanks! I prefer the use of `\v` to use standard RegEx; any way to make it default in `.vimrc` so that I don't have to type it again each time? (I should be asking as a separate question?)

Comment: @JikkuJose no option for that, there is only `magic/nomagic`.  I don't think it is a problem to stay with `magic` as default. but if you really want to have `\v` when you search, you could `nnoremap / /\v` and `nnoremap ? ?\v` personally I won't do that.

Answer (score 0):

by default vim uses strange regex matching: you need to escape the `{}` characters, so use this: `\d\{4\}` and it will match as expected

Comment: Instead of "strange", I would more neutrally call it "different": Contrary to most other regexp dialects, Vim's is optimized for ad-hoc searches.

Comment: But wouldn't a mode with standard `RegEx` helpful; not sure `\v` suffices the goal.

Comment: @JikkuJose: There's already `:set magic`, but its toggling is highly discouraged, because it breaks many plugins; your proposed toggle would suffer from the same problem.

Comment: Sure, then I should just use `\v` each time.